# Speeding up distance between all possible pairs in an array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, while-loop

I have an array of x,y,z coordinates of several (~10^10) points (only 5 shown here)

```
a= [[ 34.45  14.13   2.17]
    [ 32.38  24.43  23.12]
    [ 33.19   3.28  39.02]
    [ 36.34  27.17  31.61]
    [ 37.81  29.17  29.94]]
```

I want to make a new array with only those points which are at least some distance `d` away from all other points in the list. I wrote a code using `while` loop,

```
 import numpy as np
 from scipy.spatial import distance 

 d=0.1 #or some distance 
 i=0
 selected_points=[]
 while i < len(a):
          interdist=[]  
          j=i+1
          while j<len(a):
              interdist.append(distance.euclidean(a[i],a[j]))
              j+=1

          if all(dis >= d for dis in interdist):
              np.array(selected_points.append(a[i]))
          i+=1
```

This works, but it is taking really long to perform this calculation. I read somewhere that `while` loops are very slow.

I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how to speed up this calculation.

**EDIT:** While my objective of finding the particles which are at least some distance away from all the others stays the same, I just realized that there is a serious flaw in my code, let's say I have 3 particles, my code does the following, for the first iteration of `i`, it calculates the distances `1->2`, `1->3`, let's say `1->2` is less than the threshold distance `d`, so the code throws away particle `1`. For the next iteration of `i`, it only does `2->3`, and let's say it finds that it is greater than `d`, so it keeps particle `2`, but this is wrong! since 2 should also be discarded with particle `1`. The solution by @svohara is the correct one!

Comment: How long does it take ?

Comment: I ran overnight ~7 hrs and it's still running.

Comment: As a quick suggestion, you may not continue calculation of distances if one is bigger than `d`. It will reduce another run through the array in the clause `all(dis >= d for dis in interdist)`

Comment: Can you provide a functional script? There are no definitions of ``halos`` and ``selected_halos`` in yours

Comment: Sorry for an incomplete idea, but I remember reading awhile back an approach to k-means clustering (which also requires euclidean distance calculations) that uses the triangle inequality to reduce the number of computations required

Comment: @max : Thanks! So I am guessing I can check whether the distance is greater than d at each iteration of j and as soon as it is false, I break the iteration and go to the next i iteration. How do you break the iteration in the middle?

Comment: `break` is a keyword for breaking the loop. but you need to be aware of distances of points with less indexes than `i + 1` because now you don't take them into consideration that is not right, I suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For big data sets and low-dimensional points (such as your 3-dimensional data), sometimes there is a big benefit to using a spatial indexing method. One popular choice for low-dimensional data is the k-d tree.

The strategy is to index the data set. Then query the index using the same data set, to return the 2-nearest neighbors for each point. The first nearest neighbor is always the point itself (with dist=0), so we really want to know how far away the next closest point is (2nd nearest neighbor). For those points where the 2-NN is > threshold, you have the result.

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree as KDTree
import numpy as np

#a is the big data as numpy array N rows by 3 cols
a = np.random.randn(10**8, 3).astype('float32')

# This will create the index, prepare to wait...
# NOTE: took 7 minutes on my mac laptop with 10^8 rand 3-d numbers
#  there are some parameters that could be tweaked for faster indexing,
#  and there are implementations (not in scipy) that can construct
#  the kd-tree using parallel computing strategies (GPUs, e.g.)
k = KDTree(a)

#ask for the 2-nearest neighbors by querying the index with the
# same points
(dists, idxs) = k.query(a, 2)
# (dists, idxs) = k.query(a, 2, n_jobs=4)  # to use more CPUs on query...

#Note: 9 minutes for query on my laptop, 2 minutes with n_jobs=6
# So less than 10 minutes total for 10^8 points.

# If the second NN is > thresh distance, then there is no other point
# in the data set closer.
thresh_d = 0.1   #some threshold, equiv to 'd' in O.P.'s code
d_slice = dists[:, 1]  #distances to second NN for each point
res = np.flatnonzero( d_slice >= thresh_d )
```

Comment: A note on the query complexity. Each query is O(log(N)), with N samples, the total time complexity to complete the all-points query is on average O(N log (N)).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vectorized approach using [`distance.pdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) -

```
# Store number of pts (number of rows in a)
m = a.shape[0]

# Get the first of pairwise indices formed with the pairs of rows from a
# Simpler version, but a bit slow : idx1,_ = np.triu_indices(m,1)
shifts_arr = np.zeros(m*(m-1)/2,dtype=int)
shifts_arr[np.arange(m-1,1,-1).cumsum()] = 1
idx1 = shifts_arr.cumsum()

# Get the IDs of pairs of rows that are more than "d" apart and thus select 
# the rest of the rows using a boolean mask created with np.in1d for the 
# entire range of number of rows in a. Index into a to get the selected points.
selected_pts = a[~np.in1d(np.arange(m),idx1[distance.pdist(a) < d])]
```

For a huge dataset like `10e10`, we might have to perform the operations in chunks based on the system memory available.

Comment: The output contains all the points instead of only the ones that are d distance away from all other.

Comment: @HuShu Not sure if I follow you. It gives the same o/p as with your code in the question.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I just realized that there is a bug in my original code. Please check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

1. Drop the append, it must be really slow. You can have a static vector of distances and use [] to put the number in the right position.
2. Use min instead of all. You only need to check if the minimum distance is bigger than x.
3. Actually, you can break on your append in the moment that you find a distance smaller than your limit, and then you can drop out both points. In this way you even do not have to save any distance (unless you need them later).

   4. Since d(a,b)=d(b,a) you can do the internal loop only for the following points, forget about the distances you already calculated. If you need them you can pick the faster from the array.

From your comment, I believe this would do, if you have no repeated points.

```
selected_points = []
for p1 in a:
    save_point = True
    for p2 in a:
        if p1!=p2 and distance.euclidean(p1,p2)<d:
            save_point = False
            break
    if save_point:
        selected_points.append(p1)

return selected_points
```

In the end I check a,b and b,a because you should not modify a list while processing it, but you can be smarter using some aditional variables.

Comment: Thanks! I don't need the distances, but I am confused about how to break the iteration in j as soon as I encounter that the distance is less than d and then proceed to the next iteration of i?

Comment: The line p1!=p2 gives an error "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
" because p1 and p2 are arrays [x y z].

Comment: Did you check your typing? It worked fine here and we are not asking for the truth value of the array. I did forget he point (distance.euclidean) because I simulated it.

Comment: I copy pasted your code, at first it says "'return' outside function", then when I changed return to print, I get "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() " , are you using Python 2.7 or some other version?

Answer (score 0):

your algorithm is quadratic (10^20 operations), Here is a linear approach if distribution is nearly random. 
Splits your space in boxes of size `d/sqrt(3)^3`. Put each points in its box.

Then for each box,

- if there is just one point, you just have to calculate distance with points in a little neighborhood.
- else there is nothing to do.